# What exactly does this Spring Security configuration mean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I am unclear about how to configure **Spring Security** project into an application.

In the course documentation I found these 2 code snippets:

1) **Configuration in web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am pretty new to Java EE (and also to Spring), so reading online I understand that this **filter** is something like a **Servlet** that performs filtering tasks on either the request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the response from a resource, or both. So if the standard **Servlet** are objects used to handle request, create content and give a response (for example the HttpServlet that handle HttpRequest, and give an HttpResponse containing the view to show) the **Filter** doesn't create content but elaborate resources.

So, **Filters** are Java classes that can be used in Servlet Programming for the following purposes:

- **To intercept requests from a client before they access a resource at back end**
- **To manipulate responses from server before they are sent back to the client**

and there exists various types of filters suggested by the specifications as the **Authentication Filters** (is this the type used for Spring Security for this task?)

So what exactly do the filter declared and mapped into the previous snippet do? I think that it applies the **springSecurityFilterChain** to all the requests directed towards the **/*** URL pattern (that I think it means to all the servlet eventually declared that handle request).

Ok, but what exactly is this **springSecurityFilterChain?** . Looking here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

It seems to me that Spring doesn't use a single filter, but that this **springSecurityFilterChain** maintains a filter chain internally (so it uses more filters) where each of the filters has a particular responsibility and filters are added or removed from the configuration depending on which services are required.

But where exactly are these filter declared?

2) The second code snippet showed in the course slides is this one (and I can't understand if it is related\linked to the previous one or not):

```
<beans>
    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/edit*"
access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/account*"
access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accounts/**"
access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/customers/**"
access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

I understand that it intercepts urls and that these intercepted URLs are evaluated in the order listed (first match is used, put specific matches first).

So for example if the URL match with **/accounts/edit*** pattern it is applied the **ROLE_ADMIN** access level. But what exactly is this? Is this something that I have to write or is it something provided by Spring framework?

The other doubts are: where are this second code snipped declared? Into the XML Spring configuration file? How is it related (if a relationship exists) with the first code snippet?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

1. DelegatingFilterProxy as the name says, it only delegates the web container filter request to spring security filter chain and it never implemented Servlet Filter. Spring security filter chain are defined in the spring-security.xml file if we set auto config property for the http request all the filter chain are added.

[image]

Individually each security filter can be added like

```
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
  <property name="securityMetadataSource">
    <security:filter-security-metadata-source>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/super/**" access="ROLE_WE_DONT_HAVE"/>
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_TELLER"/>
    </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and bean defintion xml file name is added to the web container through

```
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value> classpath:**/*-security.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

2. By default spring provides few set of roles. As you are using security context in bean defintion it does lot of things. We just need to add spring-security.jar file. Even you can use ldap server for authentication for that we can put

If we want to add your own set of authentication manager service, it can be done by adding the custom authentication manager service.

```
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
  </authentication-manager>
```

Security namespace does lot of magic which is explained in 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-config-attributes, 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html